# MySQL AFTER INSERT DELETE

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need a table that consistently contains no more than 100 lines, but also an incremental ID would be used. I tried to do this with the AFTER INSERT trigger, but it does not work and I do not understand why, please, who can - explain.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `DeleteOld` AFTER INSERT ON `book`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DELETE FROM `book` WHERE `book`.`id` <  New.id - 100;

END
```

Engine MyISAM.

Comment: It does not work because you cannot action a table which fired the trigger.

Comment: Ok, fixed, thank you.